GCP alert policy for pub/sub messages which are not acknowledge for more than 30 minutes
How can I create a alert policy which should trigger an alert only when it finds messages in pub/sub subscription which are not acknowledged for more than 30 minutes.
I could see 2 options:

unacked messages: But this will trigger the alert, if it sees any message in the topic.
Oldest unacked message: Which will only give me the oldest message age out of all the messages in the topic.

But my requirement is different, so it can be achieved ?
Thanks in advance.
